# Get the specific list item based on some range

Tags: vb.net

I have class `Merge` as follows below. I also have `MergeCollection` class containing list of `Merge`. The point is there could be many merges which their `min, max and value`. Now i want to pass `passedValue` and found merge on my list that `passedValue` is between min and max. Note that there could be only one merge on list which `Max` value could be Nothing - in this case Nothing means infinitive. So we can have merge like `Min = 100 and Max = Nothing` means 100 to infinitive. I secured adding to check firstly if such merge already exists. From the other hand:

> ->if there is no merge on list that `passedValue` is between min and max function should return Nothing.
>
> ->If there would be somehow two/more merges that passedValue is within then take randomly one of them.
>
> ->if list doesn't contain any item then return Nothing

What could be the easiest way to implement such functionality?

```
Public Class Merge
      Property Min As Integer
      Property Max As Integer?
      Property Value As Double
End Class

Public Class MergeCollection      
      Private ReadOnly _merges As List(Of Merge) 

      Public Function GetMergeBy(passedValue As Integer)
            //
      End Function
      ...
End Class
```

**EDIT:** bounds are inclusive

Comment: If an answer sorts out your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to the answer - It makes sure that the user gets reputation points and makes it easier for anyone else who has the same problem to see that your question has an accepted answer that might work for them as well. (And the person answering the question gets reputation points btw)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if the bounds are inclusive or exclusive, but it's easy enough to change the conditional operators and this should get you going:

```
Public Function GetMergeBy(passedValue As Integer) As Merge
    Dim result = _merges.Where(Function(m) m.Min < passedValue AndAlso passedValue < If(m.Max,Integer.MaxValue)).ToList()

    If result.Count == 0 Then Return Nothing

    Static rnd As New Random()
    Return result(rnd.Next(result.Count))
End Function
```

Comment: I like how you literally "take randomly one of them" :)

Comment: bounds are inclusive

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Private Shared PRNG As New Random
Public Function GetMergeBy(passedValue As Integer) As Merge
    Dim mie As IEnumerable(Of Merge)
    If Me._merges IsNot Nothing Then
        'bounds are inclusive or exclusive???
        'as coded inclusive
        mie = From m In Me._merges
                Where passedValue >= m.Min AndAlso (Not m.Max.HasValue OrElse passedValue <= m.Max)
                Select m
        Return mie(PRNG.Next(mie.Count))
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

edit: Looks a lot like Joel answer ;)

Comment: bounds are inclusive